# Variadic macro in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a macro I use to generate enums, and I'd like to get Doxygen to pick these up, however I can't seem to find any information on variadic macros and doxygen.

The enum looks like this:

```
#define ENUM_DECLARATION(TYPE, ...) enum class TYPE { __VA_ARGS__ }
```

The macro actually gets much more complex because it also initializes a factory to get enums by string name and vice versa.  However I don't need doxygen to generate the extra information.

The way I've tried defining the macro in Doxygen is

```
ENUM_DECLARATION(TYPE, ...) enum class TYPE { __VA_ARGS__ };
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, with the input of

```
ENUM_DECLARATION(eTimingBits, TIMING_BLOCK_0, TIMING_BLOCK_1, TIMING_BLOCK_2, TIMING_BLOCK_3);
```

Using the -d Preprocessor option, I get an output of:

```
TIMING_BLOCK_1     eTimingBits   {TIMING_BLOCK_0   } TIMING_BLOCK_2, TIMING_BLOCK_3);
```

So it seems like doxygen has some understanding of the ellipsis but not fully.  Does anyone know if what I'm doing is currently possible, and if so how do I make Doxygen correctly generate the enum?